# Pre Office 365 Excel, vba save CSV file as UTF8 format

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub LoadData(WkSht As Worksheet, DataSourceName As String, MySQLTable As String, Append As String)

Dim CSVFile As String

WkSht.Cells.Replace ",", ""

CSVFile = "\\ant.domain.com\dept\Extracts\" & DataSourceName & ".csv"

'Save file to desktop.
WkSht.Select
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CSVFile, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8

Conn.Open "DSN=cobra2;"

'Delete old data if this table is to be wiped every time.
If Append <> "Append" Then
    Conn.Execute "TRUNCATE TABLE " & MySQLTable
End If

'Load new data in csv at high speed.
Conn.Execute "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" & Replace(CSVFile, "\", "\\") & "' " & _
             "INTO TABLE " & MySQLTable & " " & _
             "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " & _
             "LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' " & _
             "IGNORE 1 LINES"

Set Conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

The above code normally works enough to give me a UTF8 character error when trying to do the conn execute to a MySQL 5.7 instance with just FileFormat:=xlCSV.  I attempted the above change to ensure UTF8 encoding compliance and I get the strange we couldn't find anything to replace error.

What could possibly be the problem with the code?

Comment: do you get the error on the first `WkSht.Cells.Replace ",", ""` or on `Replace(CSVFile, "\", "\\")`

Comment: oh sorry, that might be better if I said where it errors.  when I F8 through it seems to error out at ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CSVFile, FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8; that could be that it is actually error out at the cells replace though I suppose.

Comment: okay so commenting out the Replace line yields a different error. 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: it could be the `ThisWorkbook` part of the line - it depends on where exactly you are running your code from and which book you actually intend to save. You might want to replace it with `ActiveWorkbook` based on the select that precedes it.

Comment: ActiveWorkbook didn't fix either error.

Comment: So it turns out that xlCSVUTF8 is not available in Excel 2016 standalone.  It is only available with the O365 version for some stupid reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileFormat:=xlCSVUTF8

Is not available currently in the Excel 2016 standalone version.  It is only available in the O365 version of Excel some where around build 16.0.7726

Comment: you should edit the title to more accurately represent the problem you were having so that you can help other people in the future with the same question :)